# SLF4J collision in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

My pom file:

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When i start an apllication i have collision:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/krasnov/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/krasnov/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.12.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

How to fix it? I want to use `log4j-slf4j-impl` for logging.

If i use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Then in log file there are my logs and more of system logs which is not needed for me

Comment: Try excluding the logging library alone from the Spring Boot, not the whole `starter-logging`. I think Spring uses logback-classic for logging so exclude that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two loggers implemented in your project :

- `logback-classic`
- `log4j-slf4j`

  You need to exclude any one of the conflicting dependencies as you have already made your mind that you do not want to exclude `log4j-slf4j` so you are left to exclude `logback-classic`. Try as shown below.

  `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>`